# Not able to generate Mingw Makfile

Tags: cmake, cmake-modules, cmake-language

cmake version : 3.18.5
I was using cmake-gui, it is working smoothly.
Now i have switched to command-line. it was working for some days and suddenly from no where i am getting the below error.

The cmake command i am running,

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" .. -DVARIANT=V1
```

The error iam geting is,

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:32 (project):
  Generator

    MinGW Makefiles

  does not support instance specification, but instance

    C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community

  was specified.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the command with source and build directory paths. Now everything is fine.
But i don't know why it was working till now with old command. anyone have answer for this?

cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -S .. -B . -DVARIANT=V1